First order non-homogeneous ODE - variation of parameters confusion

How did they get the circled part of the textbook (page 250 ODEs by William F. Trench)?
Here are my notes on the variation of parameters method:

^^ following this method for the example above, should it be $z=vx \implies z'=v'x+vx'$, So, substituting $z,z'$ back into the original ODE, we get: $$z'-\frac zx = v'x+vx'-\frac{vx}{x}=v'x+vx'-v=xe^{-x},$$ which seems a bit circular to me, because I've arrived at what seems to be another first order ODE.

You should probably use that $x'=\frac{dx}{dx}=1$, at its earliest occurrence.
